# How to add prefix to entered text?

Tags: xcode

I already know how to change the text in label box by with a text field:

```
self.titleLabel.text = self.textField.text
```

How do I add static text to text that is being entered?

If in the `textField` a name is entered, how do get the label box to display a "Hi," then whatever text that was entered?

What do I have to put in front of `self.textField.text` after the "=" sign?

Comment: While this is off-topic for programmers, I would do it like this: `NSString *i = self.textField.text; self.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your text: %@", i];`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from iOS 6.0, UILabel supports attributed text, initialize an NSMutableString object and then you can your label text using,

```
self.titleLabel.attributedText = [yourNSMSObject appendFormat:@"add your prefix text here %@",self.textField.text];
```

I hope this is your expected result.